# Struggling to click continue button with VBA code on webpage

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub login()

    Const Url$ = "https://commercial.metrobankonline.co.uk/portalserver/business-login"

    Dim UserName As String, Password As String, Scode As String, LoginData As Worksheet
    'Set LoginData = ThisWorkb ook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    UserName = "123456789" 
    Password = "pwd" 

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim Btn As Object

    With ie

        .navigate Url
        ieBusy ie
        .Visible = True

        Dim oLogin As Object, oPassword As Object
        Dim ele As Object
        Set oLogin = .document.getElementsByName("customerNo")(0)


        oLogin.Value = UserName


  End With   
For Each ele In ie.document.getelementsbytagname("a")
    If InStr(ele.innertext, "Continue") > 0 Then ele.Click
Next
ie.Quit
End Sub
```

I am struggling to move to the next step of sign-in process by clicking the "Continue" button. below codes naviges to the web page sucessufly and puts the user name but fails to click the button.

Comment: Does the website have an API? If so, you should probably be using that instead of trying to automate the front-end, which is likely against the terms of use of the site you're requesting, and will start being impossible as soon as they add a [recapcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReCAPTCHA) mechanism to block "bots".

Answer (score 1):

The code for that button is:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-disabled="" ng-click="validate()">
    Continue
</button>
```

So you want to search for `button` tags not the anchor `a` tag:

```
For Each ele In ie.document.getelementsbytagname("button")
```

Alternatively (I've never tried this myself) but since the button is calling javascript function `validate()` you may be able to do a single line instead of a for loop:

```
ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "validate();"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, looking for a "button" worked.